# Memory utilization is not going down even when the application is not in use and there is no load on the system post Java 11 update

Tags: amazon-web-services, memory, garbage-collection, java-11, autoscaling

We have deployed an application on aws which runs on 16 GB of RAM, of which the memory utilization goes upto 85 - 90% and then remains there till a full GC is triggered.
For this application, we have also implemented an autoscaling setup for AWS EC2 instances based on memory utilization.
After updating Java version to 11, we are observing that the memory utilization is not going down even when the application is not in use and there is no load on the system
For autoscaling to work properly, the average memory utilization should go below a specific percentage that we have set,
since the memory is constant at a higher percentage and not going below the lower threshold value, autoscaling is not performing as expected.
The GC Algorithm we used before was CMS, which is now changed to GC1, since then we are running into this issue.
Following are the GC parameters we are using:
-Xms6g,-Xmx12g,-verbose:gc,-Xloggc:gc.log,-XX:+PrintGCDetails,-XX:+UseG1GC,-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30,-XX:G1ReservePercent=20,-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
,-Xlog:safePoint,-XX:ThreadStackSize=1024,-XX:+OptimizeStringConcat,-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=50

With autoscaling setup, the Ec2 instances should get scaled in when the average memory utilization is below the lower threshold value, the average memory utilization is constant at a higher percentage and not coming down even when the application is not in use and there is no load on the system.

Comment: Java performs garbage collection on an as-needed basis, unless you call `System.gc()` (and, as the pedants are sure to point out, it's not guaranteed either). You can either call that function on a regular basis, or better, choose a different metric for auto-scaling.

Comment: @kdgregory Thanks for the info. Can you provide further info on what all GC attributes/params I can add so that it will have more free space?